# Automator Shell Script- Sass Compiling Shell Script no longer works

Tags: css, bash, shell, sass, automator

So I a have pretty cool & simple shell script that used to work fine-

sass_cssTheme_Compiler.sh:

```
cd  /path/to/cssFiles
perl -pi.bak -e 's/constantsLight/constantsDark/g' header.scss
sass --style compressed header.scss headerDark.css |
perl -pi.bak -e 's/constantsDark/constantsLight/g' header.scss
sass --style compressed header.scss headerLight.css
```

Basically all ^this^ does is go into my scss file and change the imported variables that the document takes before it sass-compiles it into a css file.  Then it will go back in and switch the variables that it imports and then compile it again under a different theme of variables.  Now I can upload both themed css sheets to my site in a snap.

To make it even faster, I tried to create a workflow to execute this shell script for me with a simple keyboard shortcut.  The workflow is as simple as this-
[Automator Workflow: Sass Compiling Shell Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ek1.png)

The code for the automator shell script just goes to the proper directory and executes the other shell script as such:

```
cd /path/to/cssFiles && ./sass_cssTheme_Compiler.sh
```

A few months ago it was working great... until subsequently I installed El Capitan v. 10.11.2.  Now the workflow won't run and all I see is this:

```
./sass_cssTheme_Compiler.sh: line 4: sass: command not found
./sass_cssTheme_Compiler.sh: line 6: sass: command not found
```

But sass is, and has always been, installed.  The simple commands from the workflow will still work in my terminal.. just not in Automator.
Perhaps El Capitan isn't the issue and I'm more lost than I realize but the timing of the error and the OS update is suspicious.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling ruby in hopes that the libraries will update.
I'm obviously very much a rookie so any help or hand-holding I can get with this would be great.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I experienced a similar issue after installing El Capitan. I upgraded xcode, after which I installed sass: 'sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass'  Did the trick. Found the solution here  https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  I solved my problem with a few more steps in this order-
1. I uninstalled xcode, ruby, and sass in that order

Comment: 2. I re-installed xcode, ruby, and sass in that order and according to the path location you provided and as provided in your link by ectoplasm
---And Automator Script Still not working--- so then...
3. I found a [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/my-automator-workflow-fails-because-it-fails-to-find-the-git-command-within-the) solution by Daniel Schlaug to include  "source ~/.bash_profile" at the beginning of the automator shell script
4. So I included "source ~/.bash_profile" and added the sass path to PATH variable and it worked..
SOLVED! Thanks again